# Is there a way to use react webcam on the same page one for front camera and the other for rear camera?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webcam, next.js

I am using the react-webcam version ^4.0.0. I have a web page built-in react where I would like to use the first tab to take the customer selfie and the next tab to take a picture using his rear camera.
For the front camera, I'm using the following code:-

```
    const videoConstraints = {
         facingMode: 'user'
    };
              <Webcam
                id="Selfie"
                audio={false}
                style={webcamStyle}
                videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
                height="auto"
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
                ref={webcam => (this.webcam = webcam)}
                screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
              />
```

I'm using the following code for using the rear camera:-

```
const videoConstraints = {
  facingMode: 'environment'
};
                  <Webcam
                id="panCard"
                audio={false}
                style={webcamStyle}
                height="auto"
                videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
                ref={webcam => (this.webcam = webcam)}
                screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
              />
```

The problem is even if I set the rear camera to the environment it still opens the front camera.
How do I solve this issue? Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think `<Webcam />` being a higher order function is already assigned the instance of camera in the same component. Because of this by default the next initiation opens the front camera. What would happen if you forked the package and created a duplicate of the `<Webcam />` component. Also in native development this requires some hardware acceleration i think.

Comment: From my Andro phone, it's not possible: https://jsfiddle.net/k1emoh3a/